# Powershell: AD-GET wont work with variable

Tags: powershell

I want to check if several AD users exists. I have an array (adList) from a sql query with hunderts of IDs, but i have a problem when i use this value. $($adList[22]) contains "00001120", i checked it!

Example (No Output):

```
$adList = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance BENSQLCLU001 -Query $QueryFmt | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," | Select-Object -Skip 1 | % {$_ -replace '"', ""}

$currentID = $($adList[22])
Get-ADUser -Filter {employeeNumber -eq $currentID}
Output: Nothing
```

Example (Output)

```
$currentID = 00001120
Get-ADUser -Filter {employeeNumber -eq $currentID}
Output: AD User...
```

Comment: It should work with a string.. But (there is always a but) you'll have to drop the curly braces in your filter statement when using a variable (and then use double quotes which you'll also have to escape). Sample : Get-ADUser -filter "employeeNumber -eq ""$Currentid"""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it...$adList contains strings and thats why it isn't working. Yes, i'm a noob. ;-)